# How can I configure the Jaxb2Marshaller used by mvc:annotation-driven

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jaxb

I am writing a RESTful web service using JAXB and Spring MVC. In my Spring context  takes care of a lot of helpful stuff for me, but it registers its own JAXB marshaller and I can't find a way to add properties to it (like a NamespacePrefixMapper or schema location).

Is there a way to override the default marshaller configured in  or set properties on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<mvc:annotation-driven>` is essentially a "macro" that registers a bunch of fixed config options. You can see what it does in the source of the rather dense `AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser` class.

Of particular interest here is that it registers a `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter` and injects a whole series of components into it, some of which you'll need, many of which you won't.

`<mvc:annotation-driven>` doesn't offer much in the way of customisation, though, so if you want to change what it does, you need to remove it from your context, and declare your own `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`, configured the way you want.

The JAXB marshaller is injected into the `messageConverters` property of `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter`.

Comment: I'm a bit disappointed that this is the case. You can configure your own conversionService but you can't configure you messageConverters?

Comment: @Rob: Yeah. The `<mvc>` macros weren't very well thought out, in my opinion.